# Is there anyway to format my EndPoint URL in WordPress?

Tags: rest-api, endpoints

I have wrote an endpoint in WordPress and it works just fine. The problem is with the URL. The current format of the URL request must be like this:

https://iotkidsiq.com/wp-json/zaindob/v1/sync_order/key=011900/msisdn=019009

However, The URL request must be in this format:

https://iotkidsiq.com/wp-json/zaindob/v1/sync_order?key=011900&msisdn=019009

How do I format that?

Here is my code:

```
register_rest_route( 'zaindob/v1', '/sync_order/' . 'key=' . '(?P<key>\d+)' .  '/msisdn=' . '(?P<msisdn>\d+)' , array( 

    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'updatetable',
  ) );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Query args are not part of the route URL. Your endpoint URL is:

```
https://iotkidsiq.com/wp-json/zaindob/v1/sync_order
```

So needs to be registered as:

```
register_rest_route( 'zaindob/v1', '/sync_order', array( 
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'updatetable',
) );
```

`key` and `msisdn` are *arguments* that are sent to your endpoint. To define these use set the `args` property of the endpoint options:

```
register_rest_route( 'zaindob/v1', '/sync_order', array( 
    'methods'  => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'updatetable',
    'args'     => array(
        'key'    => array(
            'type'     => 'integer',
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'msisdn' => array(
            'type'     => 'integer',
            'required' => true,
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Now your endpoint callback can accept the `key` and `msisdn` paramaters, and they are required for the endpoint to return a result:

```
function updatetable( $request ) {
    $key    = $request->get_param( 'key' );
    $msisdn = $request->get_param( 'msisdn' );

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It works perfectly now. Really appreciate it

Comment: Thank you so much.